# How to tell android studio the location of a pre-existing NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Im trying to use my pre-existing `NDK` with `Android Studio` , it offers an option of downloading a new NDK and auto setup , but i want to use the version i was using before i downloaded `Android Studio` , how to tell it the location of the `NDK` i already have ? Do i have to set the NDK_HOME environment variable ?

`Android Studio`'s documentation tells that when downloading the `NDK` from the options menu in `Android Studio` it will be under the `SDK`'s home in a folder called "ndk-bundle" , do i have to put it there ?   (soure https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Android Studio (2.2) you can go to File | Project Structure.

You will get the Project Structure dialog.  Select `SDK Location`.  You can set the location of your NDK in this dialog as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone passes by there's a work-around that doesn't involve re-downloading the NDK using Android Studio. As the OP points out Android Studio stores the Android NDK in a folder called "ndk-bundle" under the Android SDK's root folder. So, in linux, simply creating a symbolic link (a shortcut, if you use Windows) to the NDK root folder in your SDK root folder solves the problem, like so:

```
ln -s [FULL_PATH_TO_NDK_ROOT] [FULL_PATH_TO_SDK_ROOT]/ndk-bundle
```

I believe doing something similar in Windows would work.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. On Windows the command is `mklink /d ndk-bundle $PATH_TO_NDK`

Comment: Glad to have helped, mate.